# Connectivity plugin fails to build for flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, plugins, connectivity

I am using the latest version provided by the flutter team. connectivity: ^0.4.6+1
still facing this issue after migrating to AndroidX support.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'connectivity'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s


The plugin connectivity could not be built due to the issue above.
```

Comment: Have you set your ANDROID_HOME environment variable?

Comment: @easeccy I am on OSX Catalina and yes it's properly set.

Comment: I suggest you to create new project and add only the connectivity plugin. See if it works properly. Newly created projects are auto migrated to AndroidX. I've seen some cases that this was the issue.

Comment: Rebuilding the project with android x support solved the issue for me but it needs to be run from android studio and will not work for me from vs code.

Comment: There might be issue with your environment variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to the latest connectivity plugin and `flutter clean` helped. now have a issue with ios which is a bit different but will create a new thread for the same.